# Batched output in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a tables like the following

```
CREATE TABLE Company
(
Id INT
)

CREATE TABLE CompanyNumbers
(
CompanyId INT,
NumberText VARCHAR (255)
)
```

What I want as an output is this in pseudo code

Give me all the numbers for company A as a single comma separated string, if the string contains more than 150 numbers output another row with next 150 until complete.

What is the best way to achieve this? basically output batches of 150 numbers like this:

```
CompanyId | Batch
1         | 3344,444,5555,6444, 444, 44, 44555, 5555... > 150 of them 
2         | 33343,33, 2233,3 (second row if more than 150)
```

I want this to be done within a stored procedure.

Comment: Which version of `SQL Server` do you use?

Comment: I tried this out on SQL 2008 but this will be used on SQL 2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH    cb AS
        (
        SELECT  CompanyId, NumberText, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyID ORDER BY NumberText) AS rn
        FROM    CompanyNumbers
        )
SELECT  CompanyID, batch,
        (
        SELECT  CASE WHEN rn % 150 = 1 THEN '' ELSE ', ' END + NumberText AS [text()]
        FROM    cb
        WHERE   cb.CompanyID = cbd.CompanyID
                AND rn BETWEEN cbd.batch * 150 + 1 AND cbd.batch * 150 + 150
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT CompanyID, FLOOR((rn - 1) / 150) AS batch
        FROM    cb
        ) AS cbd
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near 'XML'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near 'cbd'.

Comment: I think you deserve a special badge if this works, so quick at responding too!

Comment: Sure, just confused `ROOT` and `PATH` :) Try the updated query